# Flyway: FATAL: database "users" does not exist Docker-compose

Tags: java, spring, docker, docker-compose

I have a problem. I want to do a database migration, so I have this kind of application-prod.properties:

```
spring.flyway.enabled=true
spring.flyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/users
spring.flyway.user=postgres
spring.flyway.password=1234
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration
```

Now when building containers and startup, I want the migration to run, however I see an error when starting the server:

```
serapi_1   | 2023-10-08T18:19:12.353Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : Flyway Community Edition 9.16.3 by Redgate
userapi_1   | 2023-10-08T18:19:12.354Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : See release notes here: https://rd.gt/416ObMi
userapi_1   | 2023-10-08T18:19:12.355Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    :
postgres_1  | 2023-10-08 18:19:12.845 UTC [34] FATAL:  database "users" does not exist
userapi_1   | 2023-10-08T18:19:12.897Z  WARN 1 --- [           main] onfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Unable to obtain connection from database: FATAL: database "users" does not exist
userapi_1   | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
userapi_1   | SQL State  : 3D000
userapi_1   | Error Code : 0
userapi_1   | Message    : FATAL: database "users" does not exist
userapi_1   |
userapi_1   | 2023-10-08T18:19:12.946Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :
userapi_1   |
userapi_1   | Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
userapi_1   | 2023-10-08T18:19:12.999Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
userapi_1   |
userapi_1   | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Unable to obtain connection from database: FATAL: database "users" does not exist
userapi_1   | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
userapi_1   | SQL State  : 3D000
userapi_1   | Error Code : 0
userapi_1   | Message    : FATAL: database "users" does not exist
userapi_1   |
userapi_1   |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
userapi_1   |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
userapi_1   |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
userapi_1   |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
userapi_1   |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
userapi_1   |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
userapi_1   |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
userapi_1   |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
userapi_1   |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
userapi_1   |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
userapi_1   |   at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar!/:3.1.4]
userapi_1   |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar!/:3.1.4]
userapi_1   |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar!/:3.1.4]
userapi_1   |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar!/:3.1.4]
userapi_1   |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar!/:3.1.4]
userapi_1   |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar!/:3.1.4]
userapi_1   |   at com.example.userapi.UserApiApplication.main(UserApiApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
userapi_1   |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
userapi_1   |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
userapi_1   |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
userapi_1   |   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
userapi_1   |   at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[userApi.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
userapi_1   |   at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95) ~[userApi.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
userapi_1   |   at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[userApi.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
userapi_1   |   at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[userApi.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
userapi_1   | Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: Unable to obtain connection from database: FATAL: database "users" does not exist
userapi_1   | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
userapi_1   | SQL State  : 3D000
userapi_1   | Error Code : 0
userapi_1   | Message    : FATAL: database "users" does not exist
userapi_1   |
userapi_1   |   at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:60) ~[flyway-core-9.16.3.jar!/:na]
userapi_1   |   at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcConnectionFactory.<init>(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:74) ~[flyway-core-9.16.3.jar!/:na]
userapi_1   |   at org.flywaydb.core.FlywayExecutor.execute(FlywayExecutor.java:140) ~[flyway-core-9.16.3.jar!/:na]
userapi_1   |   at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:140) ~[flyway-core-9.16.3.jar!/:na]
userapi_1   |   at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.4.jar!/:3.1.4]
userapi_1   |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1817) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
userapi_1   |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
userapi_1   |   ... 24 common frames omitted
userapi_1   | Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "users" does not exist
userapi_1   |   at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2713) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar!/:42.6.0]
userapi_1   |   at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readStartupMessages(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2825) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar!/:42.6.0]
userapi_1   |   at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.<init>(QueryExecutorImpl.java:175) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar!/:42.6.0]
userapi_1   |   at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:313) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar!/:42.6.0]
userapi_1   |   at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar!/:42.6.0]
userapi_1   |   at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:263) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar!/:42.6.0]
userapi_1   |   at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:443) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar!/:42.6.0]
userapi_1   |   at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:297) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar!/:42.6.0]
userapi_1   |   at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(SimpleDriverDataSource.java:144) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
userapi_1   |   at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:205) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
userapi_1   |   at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:169) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.12.jar!/:6.0.12]
userapi_1   |   at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:48) ~[flyway-core-9.16.3.jar!/:na]
userapi_1   |   ... 30 common frames omitted
userapi_1   |
```

That is, for some reason, docker-compose does not create the database. How can I fix this?
My docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: users
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 1234
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - /srv/db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  auth:
    build:
      context: ./auth
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /srv/photos:/srv/photos

  userapi:
    build:
      context: ./userApi
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

Comment: Drop the volume and try again - if you used this volume before (`/var/lib/postgresql/data` contains any data) with another `POSTGRES_DB`. new database is not created. If it doesn't help, please add `docker compose logs postgres -t` output to your question. If it begins with `PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization`, my assumption is correct - use another volume or drop this one first.

Comment: @STerliakov thx